find the number of ways to distribute 30 students into 6 classes where there is max 6 students per classroom
here is the full question:
Use inclusion/exclusion to find the number of ways of distributing 30
students into six classrooms assuming that each classroom has a maximum capacity
of six students.
Let $U$ be our universe of our set of $6$ classes. We will let $A_i$ be the event that the $i$-th classroom has more than $6$ students.\
Let $N$ be the total number of ways to distribute the students into the classrooms without any restrictions.\
Using inclusion/exclusion principle the number of ways such that at least one classroom has more than $6$ students is:
$$N - \sum_{i=1}^6 |A_i| + \sum_{i < j} |A_i \cap A_j| - \sum_{i < j < k} |A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k| + ... + \sum_{i < j < k < a < b < c} |A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k \cap A_a \cap A_b \cap A_c| $$
where,
$$N = \binom{30 + 6}{6} = \binom{36}{6} = \frac{36!}{6!30!} = 1947792$$\
now we need to solve for the rest of our equation
\begin{align*}
    |A_i| &= \binom{30}{6} = 593775\\
    |A_i \cap A_j| &= \binom{24}{6} = 134596\\
    |A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k| &= \binom{18}{6} = 18564\\
    |A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k \cap A_a| &= \binom{12}{6} = 924\\
    |A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k \cap A_a \cap A_b| &= \binom{6}{6} = 1\\
\end{align*}
Therefore our number of ways to distribute the students into 6 classrooms with no more than $6$ students per classroom should be,
$$1947792 - \binom{6}{1}593775 + \binom{6}{2}134596 - \binom{6}{3}18564 + \binom{6}{4}924 - \binom{6}{5}1 = 46656$$
However, I am now stuck because I have done this question using generating functions and the answer should be 462. I do not know where i have misunderstood this problem. Any help showing where i might be wrong would be greatly appreciated.

There are two major errors in your working

Your stars and bars formula is wrong. For $n$ stars, $k$ bins $(=k-1)$ bars, the formula over non-negative integers is $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ which means the starting figure should be $\binom{35}{5}$
You have reduced the stars by $6$ each time but you need to reduce by $7$ each time in order to violate the constraint.

If you correct them, you will get the right answer
$\binom{35}5 - \binom61\binom{28}5 + \binom62\binom{21}5 - \binom63\binom{14}5 + \binom64 \binom75= 462$
